# Re: Help with Boost Grammar

Tags: c++, grammar, boost-spirit

I have redesigned and extended the grammar I asked about earlier as shown below:

```
// BIFAnalyser.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
//
/*=============================================================================
    Copyright (c) Temitope Jos Onunkun 2010 
    http://www.dcs.kcl.ac.uk/pg/onun/

    Use, modification and distribution is subject to the Boost Software
    License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at
    http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
=============================================================================*/
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                                                                        //
//  B Machine parser using the Boost "Grammar" and "Semantic Actions".    // 
//                                                                        //
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include <boost/spirit/core.hpp>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::spirit;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  Semantic Actions
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//
namespace 
{



 //semantic action function on individual lexeme
    void    do_noint(char const* start, char const* end)
    {
        string  str(start, end);

 if (str != "NAT1")
        cout << "PUSH(" << str << ')' << endl;
    }

 //semantic action function on addition of lexemes
    void do_add(char const*, char const*)    
 { 
  cout << "ADD" << endl; 
 // for(vector<string>::iterator vi = strVect.begin(); vi < strVect.end(); ++vi)
 //  cout << *vi << " ";
 }

 //semantic action function on subtraction of lexemes
    void do_subt(char const*, char const*)   
 { 
  cout << "SUBTRACT" << endl; 
 }

 //semantic action function on multiplication of lexemes
    void do_mult(char const*, char const*)   
 { 
  cout << "\nMULTIPLY" << endl;
 }

 //semantic action function on division of lexemes
    void do_div(char const*, char const*)    
 { 
  cout << "\nDIVIDE" << endl; 

 }


//

//

 vector<vector<string> > flowTable;


 //semantic action function on simple substitution
    void do_sSubst(char const* start, char const* end)    
 { 
  string  str(start, end);

  //use boost tokenizer to break down tokens
  typedef boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> > Tokenizer;
  boost::char_separator<char> sep(" -+/*:=()",0,boost::drop_empty_tokens); // char separator definition
        Tokenizer tok(str, sep);
  Tokenizer::iterator tok_iter = tok.begin();

  pair<string, string > dependency; //create a pair object for dependencies


  //create a vector object to store all tokens 
  vector<string> dx;
   // 

  int counter = 0; // tracks token position

  for(tok.begin(); tok_iter != tok.end(); ++tok_iter)  //save all tokens in vector
  {
   dx.push_back(*tok_iter );
  }
  counter = dx.size();

  //
  vector<string> d_hat; //stores set of dependency pairs

  string dep; //pairs variables as string object

  //
  dependency.first = *tok.begin();
  vector<string> FV;

  for(int unsigned i=1; i < dx.size(); i++)
  {   
    //
   if(!atoi(dx.at(i).c_str()) && (dx.at(i) !=" ")) 
   {
    dependency.second = dx.at(i);
    dep = dependency.first + "|->" + dependency.second + " ";
    d_hat.push_back(dep);

    vector<string> row; 
    row.push_back(dependency.first);  //push x_hat into first column of each row

    for(unsigned int j=0; j<2; j++)
    {

     row.push_back(dependency.second);//push an element (column) into the row
    }

    flowTable.push_back(row); //Add the row to the main vector

   }
  }

  //displays internal representation of information flow table
  cout << "\n******************************\nDependency Table\n******************************\n";
  cout << "X_Hat\tDx\tG_Hat\n";
  cout << "-----------------------------\n";
  for(unsigned int  i=0; i < flowTable.size(); i++)
  {
   for(unsigned int j=0; j<2; j++)
   {
    cout << flowTable[i][j] << "\t ";
   }
   if (*tok.begin() != "WHILE" ) //if there are no global flows,
    cout << "\t{}";     //display empty set 

   cout << "\n";
  } 
  cout << "*****************************\n\n";


  for(int unsigned j=0; j < FV.size(); j++)
  {  
   if(FV.at(j) != dependency.second)
    dep = dependency.first + "|->" + dependency.second + " ";
   d_hat.push_back(dep);
  }





  cout << "PUSH(" << str << ')' << endl;

  cout << "\n****************\nDependency pairs\n****************\n";

  for(int unsigned i=0; i < d_hat.size(); i++)
   cout << d_hat.at(i) << "\n...\n";

  cout << "\nSIMPLE SUBSTITUTION\n\n";

 }

    //semantic action function on multiple substitution
 void do_mSubst(char const* start, char const* end)    
 { 
  string  str(start, end);


  cout << "PUSH(" << str << ')' << endl;
  //cout << "\nMULTIPLE SUBSTITUTION\n\n";
 } 


 //semantic action function on unbounded choice substitution
 void do_mChoice(char const* start, char const* end)    
 { 
  string  str(start, end);

  cout << "PUSH(" << str << ')' << endl;
  cout << "\nUNBOUNDED CHOICE SUBSTITUTION\n\n";
 } 


 void do_logicExpr(char const* start, char const* end)    
 { 
  string  str(start, end);

  //use boost tokenizer to break down tokens
  typedef boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> > Tokenizer;
  boost::char_separator<char> sep(" -+/*=:()><",0,boost::drop_empty_tokens); // char separator definition
        Tokenizer tok(str, sep);
  Tokenizer::iterator tok_iter = tok.begin();

  //pair<string, string > dependency; //create a pair object for dependencies


  //create a vector object to store all tokens 
  vector<string> dx;

  for(tok.begin(); tok_iter != tok.end(); ++tok_iter)  //save all tokens in vector
  {
   dx.push_back(*tok_iter );
  }

  for(unsigned int i=0; i<dx.size(); i++)
   if(!atoi(dx.at(i).c_str()) && (dx.at(i) !=" ") ) 
   {
    cout << "\nFree Variables: " << dx.at(i)<< endl;
   }


  cout << "PUSH(" << str << ')' << endl;
  cout << "\nPREDICATE\n\n";
 } 


 void  do_predicate(char const* start, char const* end)    
 { 
  string  str(start, end);

  cout << "PUSH(" << str << ')' << endl;
  cout << "\nMULTIPLE PREDICATE\n\n";
 } 


 void do_ifSelectPre(char const* start, char const* end)    
 { 
  string  str(start, end);

  //if

  cout << "PUSH(" << str << ')' << endl;
  cout << "\nPROTECTED SUBSTITUTION\n\n";
 } 


 //semantic action function on machine substitution
 void do_machSubst(char const* start, char const* end)    
 { 
  string  str(start, end);



  cout << "PUSH(" << str << ')' << endl;
  cout << "\nMACHINE SUBSTITUTION\n\n";
 } 
} 

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  Machine Substitution Grammar
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//  Simple substitution grammar parser with integer values removed
struct Substitution : public grammar<Substitution>
{
    template <typename ScannerT>
    struct definition
    {
        definition(Substitution const& )
        {

   machine_subst
     = (  (simple_subst)
        | (multi_subst)
        | (if_select_pre_subst)
        | (unbounded_choice) )[&do_machSubst]
     ;


   unbounded_choice
     = str_p("ANY") >> ide_list
     >> str_p("WHERE") >> predicate
     >> str_p("THEN")   
     >> machine_subst
     >> str_p("END")
     ;

   if_select_pre_subst
     = (  (  str_p("IF") >> predicate >> str_p("THEN") >> machine_subst 
     >> *( str_p("ELSIF") >> predicate >> machine_subst )
     >> !( str_p("ELSE") >> machine_subst) 
     >> str_p("END") )
     | ( str_p("SELECT") >> predicate >> str_p("THEN") >> machine_subst
     >> *( str_p("WHEN") >> predicate >> machine_subst )
     >> !( str_p("ELSE") >> machine_subst) 
     >> str_p("END"))
     | ( str_p("PRE") >> predicate >> str_p("THEN") >> machine_subst 
     >> str_p("END") )  )[&do_ifSelectPre]
     ;



   multi_subst
     = ( (machine_subst) 
     >> *( ( str_p("||") >> (machine_subst) ) 
     |     ( str_p("[]") >> (machine_subst) ) )  ) [&do_mSubst]
     ;

   simple_subst
     = (identifier
     >> str_p(":=") >> arith_expr) [&do_sSubst]
     ;

   expression
     = predicate
     | arith_expr
     ;

   predicate
     = ( (logic_expr) 
     >> *( ( ch_p('&') >> (logic_expr) )
     |   ( str_p("OR") >> (logic_expr) ) ) )[&do_predicate]
     ;

   logic_expr 
     = ( identifier
     >> (str_p("<") >> arith_expr)
     | (str_p("<")  >> arith_expr)
     | (str_p("/:")  >> arith_expr)
     | (str_p("<:")  >> arith_expr)
     | (str_p("/<:")  >> arith_expr)
     | (str_p("<<:")  >> arith_expr)
     | (str_p("/<<:")  >> arith_expr)
     | (str_p("<=")  >> arith_expr)
     | (str_p("=")  >> arith_expr)
     | (str_p(">=")  >> arith_expr)
     | (str_p("=>")  >> arith_expr)
     )  [&do_logicExpr]
     ;

   arith_expr
     =   term
     >>  *(   ('+' >> term)[&do_add]
     |   ('-' >> term)[&do_subt] )
          ;

   term
     =   factor
     >>  *(   ('*' >> factor)[&do_mult]
     |   ('/' >> factor)[&do_div]  )
     ;


   factor
     =   lexeme_d[( identifier | +digit_p)[&do_noint]]
          |   '(' >> expression >> ')'
          |   ('+' >> factor)
          ;


   ide_list
     = identifier 
     >> *( ch_p(',') >> identifier )
     ;


   identifier
     = alpha_p >> +( alnum_p | ch_p('_') )
     ;

  }

  rule<ScannerT> machine_subst, unbounded_choice, if_select_pre_subst, multi_subst, 
        simple_subst, expression, predicate, logic_expr, arith_expr, 
        term, factor, ide_list, identifier;

        rule<ScannerT> const&
        start() const 
  { 
   return predicate; 
   //return multi_subst; 
   //return machine_subst; 
  }
    };
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  Main program
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int
main()
{
    cout << "************************************************************\n\n";
    cout << "\t\t...Machine Parser...\n\n";
    cout << "************************************************************\n\n";
   // cout << "Type an expression...or [q or Q] to quit\n\n";

 string str;
 int machineCount = 0;
 char strFilename[256]; //file name store as a string object
 do
 {

 cout << "Please enter a filename...or [q or Q] to quit:\n\n "; //prompt for file name to be input
 //char strFilename[256]; //file name store as a string object
 cin >> strFilename;

 if(*strFilename == 'q' || *strFilename == 'Q') //termination condition
   return 0;

 ifstream inFile(strFilename); // opens file object for reading
 //output file for truncated machine (operations only)

   if (inFile.fail())    
   cerr << "\nUnable to open file for reading.\n" << endl;

 inFile.unsetf(std::ios::skipws); 


    Substitution elementary_subst;  //  Simple substitution parser object


    string next;

 while (inFile >> str)
    {
  getline(inFile, next);

  str += next;

        if (str.empty() || str[0] == 'q' || str[0] == 'Q')
            break;

   parse_info<> info = parse(str.c_str(), elementary_subst >> !end_p, space_p);

   if (info.full)
   {
    cout << "\n-------------------------\n";
    cout << "Parsing succeeded\n";
    cout << "\n-------------------------\n";
   }
   else
   {
    cout << "\n-------------------------\n";
    cout << "Parsing failed\n";
    cout << "stopped at: " << info.stop << "\"\n";
    cout << "\n-------------------------\n";
   }

 }


}
while ( (*strFilename != 'q' || *strFilename !='Q')); 

    return 0;
}
```

However, I am experiencing the following unexpected behaviours on testing:

The text files I used are:

```
f1.txt,  ... containing ...:  debt:=(LoanRequest+outstandingLoan1)*20 .
f2.txt,  ... containing ...:  debt:=(LoanRequest+outstandingLoan1)*20 || newDebt := loanammount-paidammount || price := purchasePrice + overhead + bb .
f3.txt,  ... containing ...:  yy < (xx+7+ww) .
f4.txt,  ... containing ...:  yy < (xx+7+ww) & yy : NAT .
```

When I use multi_subst as start rule both files (f1 and f2) are parsed correctly;

When I use machine_subst as start rule file f1 parse correctly, while file f2 fails, producing the error: `“Parsing failed 
stopped at:  || newDebt := loanammount-paidammount || price := purchasePrice + overhead + bb”`

When I use predicate as start symbol, file f3 parse correctly, but file f4 yields the error: `“ 
“Parsing failed
stopped at:  & yy : NAT”`

Can anyone help with the grammar, please? It appears there are problems with the grammar that I have so far been unable to spot.

Comment: For new projects I very much suggest not to use the older Spirit.Classic version (as you do), but to utilize the newer Spirit V2.x which has been released with Boost V1.41. The new version is not only a lot easier to use, it's quite a bit faster at parse time as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have redesigned the grammar as follows, and that seem to have fixed the problem:

subst 
                    = multi_choice 
                    | machine_subst
                    ;

```
        multi_choice 
                = machine_subst
                >> +( str_p("[]") >> machine_subst )
                ;


        machine_subst
                = (  multi_subst 
                | simple_subst
                | if_select_pre_subst
                | unbounded_choice )[&do_machSubst]
                ;
```

...
...

multi_subst
                    = ( simple_subst

> > +( str_p("||") >> simple_subst ) 
> >                           ) [&do_mSubst]
> >                         ;

```
        simple_subst
                = (identifier
                >> str_p(":=") >> arith_expr) [&do_sSubst]
                ;

        expression
                = predicate
                | logic_expr
                | arith_expr
                ;

        predicate
                = ( logic_expr 
                >> +( ( str_p("&") >> logic_expr )
                |     ( str_p("OR") >> logic_expr ) ) )[&do_predicate]
                ;

        logic_expr 
                = ( identifier
                >> ( (str_p("<") >> arith_expr)
                | (str_p(">")  >> arith_expr)
                | (str_p("/:")  >> arith_expr)
                | (str_p("<:")  >> arith_expr)
                | (str_p("/<:")  >> arith_expr)
                | (str_p("<<:")  >> arith_expr)
                | (str_p("/<<:")  >> arith_expr)
                | (str_p("<=")  >> arith_expr)
                | (str_p("=")  >> arith_expr)
                | (str_p(">=")  >> arith_expr)
                | (str_p("=>")  >> arith_expr) )
                )  [&do_logicExpr]
                ;
```

...
...
I now use the start rule "subst" for files f1.txt and f2.txt and "expression" for f3.txt and f4.txt.

start() const 
        { 
            return subst; 
            //return machine_subst; 
            //return expression;
            //return if_select_pre_subst;
            //return multi_choice;
            //return unbounded_choice;
        }

I am still building the grammar up, so if I have any further issues, I will post it.